# Установка SSL VPN-Plus Client на Linux

Tags: linux, vpn

Подскажите где и как можно скачать SSL VPN-Plus Client на Astra linux 1.7.4?

Comment: Там же и так же, как и на любом другом линуксе

Comment: @andreymal, это ж астра. если включен защищённый режим (не помню, как именно они там его обозвали), то фигушки программа linux даст запустить произвольный блоб. только подписанный.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если у автора проблема проблема с подписью, то, наверное, об этом стоило бы упомянуть в вопросе. А то пока что выглядит так, будто автор вообще не попытался сделать хоть что-нибудь

Comment: Да, Яндекс говорит, что `Special`. Автор, ты ж значит это покупал, верно? Прям за деньги. А там в контракте на покупку ничего не говорится про техподдержку? Заодно спроси - читает ли их саппорт тег `astra` тут, на ruSO.

Comment: Скорее всего юзер хочет этим впном обойти службу безопасности своей конторы

Comment: Тогда решает не vpn, а бутылка колы/коньяка админу. Реально эффективнее.